# how do I unblock self-signed SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl, networking, server, ssl-certificate

Issue:  users can't log into mobile app due to "unable to contact server"

debugging message: "TypeError: Network request failed"

Attempted fixes:  restarted server, verified that db is running and nothing has changed, restarted VM that server is running on, I checked the api using postman.  When I ran a simple POST request I got the following message:

> There was an error connecting to
>   https://app.something.com/api/Accounts/5076/sometest?filter%5Bwhere%5D%xxxxx%5D=null&access_token=mwVfUBNxxxxxxx5x4A4Y5DktKnTZXeL6CB34MoP.

One of the suggestions I was given was:

> Self-signed SSL certificates  are being blocked: Fix this by turning
>   off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General

As soon as I followed this step, I was able to make the POST request and everything seemed to work fine.  I'm completely new to this type of error.  Allso, I did not set up this app/db/certificates.  So, other than unblocking self-signed SSL certificates(which seems like a really bad idea), I'm not sure how to proceed.  What are my options?

here's what the result of examining the certificate:

```
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0 poll
errornotBefore=Jan 28 11:54:38 2019 GMT
notAfter=Apr 28 11:54:38 2019 GMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either, [purchase a signed certificate](https://www.google.com/searchq=ssl+certificates) from a CA if you plan to expose this to the public.

Or the free option is to use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), with this service, you are issues free certificates, however they expire in a relatively short period of time; most of the time however you can run an agent which will automatically rotate the certificates before they expire.

The third option is to [install the CA certificate](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/AddRootToFirefox) that was used to self sign this, into to your browser. i.e., like a large company might do.

*edit*

Seems like it might instead be an expired certificate? Check when it expires with this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.stackoverflow.com -connect www.stackoverflow.com:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

*change both instances of **stackoverflow** you your domain*

Comment: according to the takeover file I received "The server is currently hosted on Microsoft Azure, uses Cafe24 as its DNS host and Gabia as its Domain Name Registrar. The app uses HTTPS to communicate with the server and makes use of the free Lets Encrypt certificate. Certbot ACME client is being used and is configured to automatically renew the certificate so there’s no need for any manual input, unless you want to add an additional domain for Let’s Encrypt to handle."

Comment: lol, Let's Encrypt is option 3, and I can add that to my answer. :et's encrypt offers free certificates, but with a relatively short expiration time. It is possible that the agent responsible for rotating the cert had failed, and instead of being self signed, the cert is simply past it's expiration date.

Comment: Examine your existing certificate with this command if you have OpenSSL installed anywhere: `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.stackoverflow.com -connect www.stackoverflow.com:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates`

Comment: I updated the original post.  I'm guessing the line "No client certificate CA names sent" is a not a good thing.

Comment: Can you double check the command you ran? This does not seem correct... I also updated my comment. Make sure that you change the parameters in my request to match your domain. Please make a note of which fields you scrub for obscurity.

Comment: Thank you for updating.  Here's the response: depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
poll errornotBefore=Jan 28 11:54:38 2019 GMT
notAfter=Apr 28 11:54:38 2019 GMT

Comment: `notAfter=Apr 28 11:54:38 2019 GMT` Whelp, there you go. It is currently about [2am, April 30, GMT](https://www.google.com/search?q=time+gmt). Your certificate is expired. Talk to your host and see if they offer a daemon which rotates the Let's Encrypt certificate, else you might need to do it manually.

Comment: Any recommendations for a paid signed certificate?  Seems like free was convenient at the time, but I'd like to prevent this type of mishap moving forward.

Comment: I use [these](https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-positivessl) for cheep, but now we are getting off topic. Seems I've solved your issue :)

Comment: I reread your first comment here, it simply seems like `Certbot ACME client` is malfunctioning, and should have handled the rotation of the cert.